# How do I sort a <ul> list by datetime?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I have a `<ul>` list which is generated using javascript when the page loads (by appending a var with `<li>` tags to a `<ul>` element).

How can I make it so the `<li>` with the NEWEST date is at the top when the page loads?

Also, my code is extremely long (~6000 words) and include outside sources (to google's api), but I understand how I can implement this into my code. Here's some pseudo-code to explain how I get stuff generated into the js/html:

- I have a `<ul>` element with nothing inside the tags
- I get information about a user's last 5 uploaded videos from youtube using google's API, this information includes channel name, video title, video ID, thumbnail URL, and the date and time the video was published at (a string with the ISO 8601 format).
- Next this information is used to make a var (which includes html tags and styles) for example:

```js
var output = '<li><p>'+VideoTitle+'</p><p>'+publishedAt+'</p>\
              <img src="'+videoThumbnail+'" height="90px"></li>'
```

- This code is added via 2 functions. 1 gets the information from localStorage using a function called "addUsers()" which is essentially just a for loop which grabs the key from localstorage and uses it as a var and parses it through a parameter to the function which adds it to the < ul > list. and 2 it gets information from an text field input (upon clicking a button as well) activates the function "addUserLocalStorage()" which adds the username to the localStorage, and also displays the youtube videos on screen as well; on refresh it gets the information from the addUsers() function.

So obviously it'd be super easy to just add the publishedAt var anywhere I wanted in the element without much hassle. but it's more about how I will implement it and use it to help sort the unordered list and make it ordered.

Any suggestions welcome as usual :)

Comment: Just FYI, `<ul>` stands for *unordered list*. Seems like `<ol>` would be a more appropriate tag to use

Comment: Think you need to show the loop which iterates over the results of the Youtube Api call. Also Is 'publishedAt' a string or javascript Date object?

Comment: @PeteG I'll add the for loop now in the original edit, also the datetime is a string in ISO 8601 format (YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sZ)

Comment: So create an array with the data, sort it by the date, loop the newly sorted array, and add the items.

Comment: @epascarello easier said than done, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: Well I do not know your data format so it is hard to actually give you an answer. What does the response look like?

Comment: @epascarello the response is in the form of a string that has the ISO 8601 format (YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sZ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery maybe [this](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/sort-a-list) will help? Which credits Bill Richards for [this blog post](http://www.wrichards.com/blog/2009/02/jquery-sorting-elements/).

**EDIT:** Also, you might want to consider using a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) to sort by - in unix time. That's easier and faster to sort by than having to parse text.

Comment: This is interesting, but as mentioned on the page it isn't viable on modern browsers.

Comment: There is a [comment](http://www.wrichards.com/blog/2009/02/jquery-sorting-elements/#comment-1070109102) by **Rasmus Schultz** that shows a similar approach using a jQuery fn. I think that's a pretty straight forward approach that surely can be tweaked to whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

I found a plugin called [TinySort](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/index.html) which seems to do exactly what I'm looking for. If I just convert my date string to a unix timecode it'll work just by sorting them from lowest number to highest.

Answer (score -2):

You can not sort data on (unorderd list) you need to use javascript or jquery to order data every time the page loads then put sorted data in  element.

Comment: This is what I'm asking, though. How would I do it using jquery or javscript?